# Html Web Radio stuck in smartphone

Tags: html, webradio

i have create a html code for my web radio player in my site...in pc browser is ok except sometimes but when i open the page from my smartphone i need to refresh page 1-2 times and after plays as the browser?Can i have a solution.Thanks.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
     src="https://radio.streamings.gr/system/player.js"></script>
     <div class="cc_player" data-username="panicradio">Loading ...</div>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. I tried your script but it works for me on mobile too.

Comment: https://panicradio.gr/     check my site with web player.Sometime when i open from my browser don't load but when i refresh it all is good.From mobile i nedd 1-2 refresh to load player.

Comment: the site is not working, it gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: k.jPlayer is not a function

Comment: yeah this is the problem now because i have "not secure" link after some changes.And when you press load in player says load stalled for chrome browser.But from edge play. can you help me with htmp code?

Answer (score 0):

try to insert the script at the end like this

```
<!-- jQuery js -->
<script src="http://panicradio.gr/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper js -->
<script src="http://panicradio.gr/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap js -->
<script src="http://panicradio.gr/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- All js -->
<script src="http://panicradio.gr/js/poca.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- Active js -->
<script src="http://panicradio.gr/js/default-assets/active.js"></script>

<script src="https://radio.streamings.gr/system/player.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still the same problem...maybe is player problem or server delay? i want to test another player but i don't know how i change the code

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Poca- Podcast &amp; Audio Template">
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Title -->
  <title>Panic Radio</title>

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" href="./img/core-img/favicon.ico">

  <!-- Core Stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Preloader -->
  <div id="preloader">
    <div class="preloader-thumbnail">
      <img src="./img/core-img/preloader.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ***** Header Area Start ***** -->
  <header class="header-area">
    <!-- Main Header Start -->
    <div class="main-header-area">
      <div class="classy-nav-container breakpoint-off">
        <!-- Classy Menu -->
        <nav class="classy-navbar justify-content-between" id="pocaNav">

          <!-- Logo -->
          <a class="nav-brand" href="index.html"><img src="./img/core-img/mini logo.png" alt=""></a>

          

              

              <!-- Top Social Area -->
              <div class="top-social-area">
              
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Panic-Radio-113597610324558/" class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/panic_radio_/" class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzkzLC1Ce9QHGqa_AFbdRDw/featured?disable_polymer=1" class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></a>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Nav End -->
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- ***** Header Area End ***** -->

  <!-- ***** Welcome Area Start ***** -->
  <section class="welcome-area">
    <!-- Welcome Slides -->
  <!-- Single Welcome Slide -->
      <div class="welcome-welcome-slide bg-img bg-overlay" style="background-image: url(img/bg-img/2.jpg);">
        <div class="container h-100">
          <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
            <div class="col-8">
              <!-- Welcome Text -->
              <div class="welcome-text">
                <h2 data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="100ms">Listen Now</h2>
                 
               
               
          
                  
                
                  <!-- Music Player -->
                 
                 <div class="cc_player" data-username="panicradio">Loading ...</div>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://radio.streamings.gr/system/player.js"></script>
                                   <h5 >Αν δεν παίζει,κάντε refresh </h5>      
</div>

                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      

    </div>
  </section>
 

    
       
        

  

<!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> All rights reserved | This template is made with <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="https://colorlib.com" target="_blank">Colorlib</a>
<!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. --></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        
  <!-- ******* All JS ******* -->
<!-- jQuery js -->
<script src="http://panicradio.gr/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper js -->
<script src="http://panicradio.gr/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap js -->
<script src="http://panicradio.gr/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- All js -->
<script src="http://panicradio.gr/js/poca.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- Active js -->
<script src="http://panicradio.gr/js/default-assets/active.js"></script>

<script src="https://radio.streamings.gr/system/player.js"></script> 

</body>

</html>
```